# SMTP Email and ERR_CONNECTION_RESET Error in Angular Project

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, email, smtp

Hi when i use the below code in angular api project my requests are not getting saved and i am gettign this following error. And when i **comment** the code to send mail everything is working fine

ERROR in console

```
 polyfills POST net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

And code to send mail

```
 public async Task SendEmail(string email, string subject, string firstName, string contact)
    {
        try
        {
            string message = BuildMessageBody(firstName, email, contact);

            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = _configuration["Email:Email"],
                    Password = _configuration["Email:Password"]
                };

                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = networkCredential;
                client.Host = _configuration["Email:Host"];
                client.Port = int.Parse(_configuration["Email:Port"]);
                client.EnableSsl = true;

                using (var emailMessage = new MailMessage())
                {
                    emailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
                    emailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress("my cc adddress"));
                    emailMessage.From = new MailAddress(_configuration["Email:Email"]);
                    emailMessage.Subject = subject;
                    emailMessage.Body = message;
                    emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    emailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    emailMessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
                    emailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(_configuration["Email:Email"]));

                    client.SendCompleted += (s, e) => {
                        client.Dispose();
                        emailMessage.Dispose();
                    };
                    await client.SendMailAsync(emailMessage);
                }
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _appLogger.CreateLog("SendEmail - " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any idea why this behaviour???

Comment: Does there have detailed error message? Which kind of browser are you using to display the web site, try to use Chrome browser and Microsoft Edge browser? Besides, about the SMTP, please check whether the email address, port and the email host server are correct?

Comment: Hi i am using Chrome only. Now i moved email sending functionality to separate controller and testing the behaviour. will lt you know once after this testing. Port, host everything is correct because from my local host i can send mail without any issues

Comment: I have a G Suite Email that is using a domain I own on GoDaddy. I also host on GoDaddy. I DO NOT HAVE a workspace email. I have all MX records set up. That said, I cannot get SMTP working with my Gmail, Contact Form 7, and GoDaddy.